# How to record continously with Androids AudioRecord?

Tags: java, android

I try to record with AudioRecord, the problem I think I have is, that the read method recall is to fast, means that the `audioBuffer` has overlapped data. How can I process the buffer as soon as this is full? And that continously.
Thank you for every answer.

```
public class Record {

/**
 * TAG for "Android monitor" while debugging
 */
private static final String LOG_TAG = Record.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * calling activity needed for callback functions.
 */
private MainActivity mActivity;

// ???
private final int SAMPLE_RATE = 48000; // Samples per s
private final int BAUD_RATE = 8000; // Symbols per s
private final double T_SYMBOL = 1/(double) BAUD_RATE; // Symbol period in s
private final int NUM_SAMPLES = (int) (T_SYMBOL * SAMPLE_RATE); // Number of samples per symbol
private final int MAX_FRAMES = 3; // Maximum possible number of frames receiving in one sequence
private final int SYMBOLS_PER_FRAME = 10 * 2; // 10 from Uart and 2 because Manchester
private final int MIN_BUFFER_SIZE = MAX_FRAMES * SYMBOLS_PER_FRAME * NUM_SAMPLES;

private final short POS_THRESHOLD = 25000;
private final short NEG_THRESHOLD = -POS_THRESHOLD;
// ???

/**
 * Record handling
 *
 * @param activity the calling activity
 */
public Record(MainActivity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
}

// ========================================================================================== //

/**
 * Record the sensor data from the MIC Channel.
 */
public void recordData(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);

            // Buffer size in bytes
            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            if (bufferSize == AudioRecord.ERROR ||
                    bufferSize == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE ||
                    bufferSize < MIN_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                bufferSize = MIN_BUFFER_SIZE;
            }

            short[] audioBuffer = new short[bufferSize / 2];

            AudioRecord record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    SAMPLE_RATE,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    bufferSize);

            if (record.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, mActivity.getString(R.string.log_ar_not_init));
                return;
            }
            record.startRecording();

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, mActivity.getString(R.string.log_start_recording));

            int firstSample = 0;
            boolean firstSampleFound = false;

            final short[] sample = new short[MIN_BUFFER_SIZE];
            short[] tempBuffer = new short[2 * bufferSize];

            while (mActivity.getSupplySensor()) {

                record.read(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length);

                // Check if data are in the audio buffer (find first sample).
                // When yes, copy the audio buffer in the first part of the temp buffer.
                // Read the audio Buffer again.
                // Copy the audio buffer in the second part of the temp buffer.
                if(!firstSampleFound) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < audioBuffer.length; i++) {
                        if ((audioBuffer[i] > POS_THRESHOLD) && !firstSampleFound) {
                             //|| audioBuffer[i] < NEG_THRESHOLD
                            firstSample = i;
                            firstSampleFound = true;
                            arraycopy(audioBuffer, 0, tempBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    arraycopy(audioBuffer, 0, tempBuffer, audioBuffer.length, audioBuffer.length);
                    arraycopy(tempBuffer, firstSample, sample, 0, MIN_BUFFER_SIZE);

                    firstSampleFound = false;
                    firstSample = 0;

                    // Begin: Used for debugging
                    for (int i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
                        String el = Integer.toString(i);
                        String elVal = Integer.toString(sample[i]);
                        Log.e("sample", "not zero " + el + " " + elVal);
                    }

                    // Clear audio buffer
                    for(int i = 0; i < audioBuffer.length; i++){
                        audioBuffer[i] = 0;
                    }
                    // End: Used for debugging
                    if(mActivity.getSupplySensor()) {
                        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mActivity.processData(sample);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            record.stop();
            record.release();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, mActivity.getString(R.string.log_stop_recording));

            /*
            // Begin: Used for debugging
            for (int i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
                String el = Integer.toString(i);
                String elVal = Integer.toString(sample[i]);
                Log.e("sample", "not zero " + el + " " + elVal);
            }
            // End: Used for debugging
            */

        }
    }).start();
}
}
```